# White spaces instead of NULL in Hive table after Sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I created sqoop process which imports data from MS SQL to Hive, but I have a problem with 'char' type fields. Sqoop import code:

```
sqoop import \
    --create-hcatalog-table \
    --connect "connection_parameters" \
    --username USER \
    --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver \
    --null-string '' \
    --null-non-string '' \
    --class-name TABLE_X \
    --hcatalog-table TABLE_X_TEST \
    --hcatalog-database default \
    --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orc tblproperties ('orc.compress'='SNAPPY')" \
    --map-column-hive "column_1=char(10),column_2=char(35)" \
    --num-mappers 1 \
    --query "select top 10 "column_1", "column_2" from TABLE_X where \$CONDITIONS" \
    --outdir "/tmp"
```

`column_1` which is type `char(10)` should be NULL if there is no data. But Hive fills the field with 10 spaces.

`column_2` which is type `char(35)` should be NULL too, but there are 35 spaces.

It is huge problem because I cannot run query like this:

```
select count(*) from TABLE_X_TEST where column_1 is NULL and column_2 is NULL;
```

But I have to use this one:

```
select count(*) from TABLE_X_TEST where column_1 = '          ' and column_2 = '                                   ';
```

I tried change query parameter and use trim function:

```
--query "select top 10 rtrim(ltrim("column_1")), rtrim(ltrim("column_2")) from TABLE_X where \$CONDITIONS"
```

but it does not work, so I suppose it is not a problem with source, but with Hive.

How I can prevent Hive from inserting spaces in empty fields?

Comment: What do you mean when you say using rtrim and ltrim doesn't work?  Error? Still getting what looks like white spaces?  Are you sure there aren't hidden characters in there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change these parameters:

```
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
```

Hive, by default, expects that the `NULL` value will be encoded using the string constant `\N`. Sqoop, by default, encodes it using the string constant `null`. To rectify the mismatch, you’ll need to override Sqoop’s default behavior with Hive’s using parameters `--null-string` and `--null-non-string` (this is what you do but with incorrect values). For details, see [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these parameters are not the problem. I tried use sign '\\N' and a lot of others but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried without giving the options of null-string and null-non-string for creating orc tables using Sqoop hcatalog, all the nulls in source are reflecting as NULL and I am able to query using is null function.

Let me know if you found any other solution to handle null's.